# SwiftUI animate background color change when a condition is met

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to change the background color of the `Text` component, whenever a given condition is met, in this example, when `numberOfTaps = 3`, which I'm able to do by having the condition inside the `.background` property call

What I'm trying to do is to change the background with an animation, nothing too fancy, just something like `.easeInOut` might work; how can I do that?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numberOfTaps = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Up") {
                numberOfTaps += 1
            }
            
            Text("\(numberOfTaps)")
                .padding()
                .background(numberOfTaps == 3 ? Color.blue : Color.green)
            
            Button("Down") {
                numberOfTaps -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of the current UI:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your body. Lets try this for easeInOut animation:-

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                numberOfTaps += 1
                color = (numberOfTaps == 3) ? Color.blue: Color.green
            } label: {
                Text("Up")
            }
            Text("\(numberOfTaps)")
                .padding()
                .background(color.animation(.easeInOut))
            
            Button {
                numberOfTaps -= 1
                color = (numberOfTaps == 3) ? Color.blue: Color.green
            } label: {
                Text("Down")
            }
        }
    }
```

> Note:- You can play with different animation property eg. easeIn,
> easeOut etc

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your conditions inside the withAnimation{} will automatically apply animation to all the related Views to these conditions/data

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var numberOfTaps = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Up") {
            //put your condition inside this wrap
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                numberOfTaps += 1
            }
        }
        
        Text("\(numberOfTaps)")
            .padding()
            .background(numberOfTaps == 3 ? Color.blue : Color.green)
        
        Button("Down") {
            numberOfTaps -= 1
        }
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```